# Categories in DNN Wiki module?

Tags: dotnetnuke, wiki

I am trying to use the DNN Wiki module to house a large document that is broken down into sections. So for example, Chapter 1 has an Introduction, 3 Parts, and an Appendix; and Chapter 2 has an Introduction, 6 Parts, and an Appendix; and so on.

I can't seem to get a tree structure hierarchy going to maintain this sort of hierarchy in the Wiki module. That is to say, I want to put an Introduction, Part I, II, II, and an Appendix all under Chapter 1 as a category (in the way a Wikipedia article is organized to have subsections). Is there a way to get that sort of hierarchy in that module, or should I look in other places?

Comment: It seems like there is no functionality for this in the current version of the Wiki module. Any suggestions for another module that may do this?

Comment: Are you talking about something like this? http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Getting-Started.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in the free Wiki module available for DNN you would have to create the hierarchy and navigation through that hierarchy yourself, as categories and tagging aren't part of the module currently.

You could do this with HTML ordered or unordered lists, ex

```
<ul>
<li>[[Category1]]
    <ul><li>[[SubCat1]]</li></ul>
</li>

<li>[[Category2]]
    <ul><li>[[SubCat2]]</li></ul>
</li>
<li>[[Category3]]
    <ul><li>[[SubCat3]]</li></ul>
</li></ul>
```

Comment: Ah yes, this would resolve the issue. However, I decided to use the native book hierarchy in Drupal instead.